# Is there a better way to call .net 4.0 code from a IIS hosted .net 2.0 application than COM?

Tags: .net, com, iis-7

I would like to call a .net 4.0 dll from an IIS7 application that is running in a .net 2.0 app pool. I've been researching this and everything I've found so far either said it wasn't possible, or you had to use COM. I have a prototype that uses COM to call the 4.0 from the 2.0 and that works, but I was curious if there was a better way?

--Edit--

In this case it need to be "auto" hosted, by that I mean no additional config really required. so WCF and other similar web services are out. Although I realize that COM has to be registered, it's within existing functionality that we're using so it's "free" so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Create a WCF service and call that, that will give you the option to run the serivce on a remote machine or locally and use the local machine transports that wcf provides (Named pipes)

-edit-

Sorry, i assume you can run .net 3.5 as well, that might not be the case.

Comment: The .NET framework version of the WCF service doesn't matter. It is the version of the WCF client that would since it runs in the .NET 2.0 app pool. Also, you could configure the WCF service hosting the .NET 4.0 code to use the netNamedPipeBinding to get "shared memory" level performance. Just think of WCF as DCOM ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately in this case this wouldn't work, we need to not have this hosted by something else. Well technically COM is hosted by something else, but it's an automatic hosting, no major config required. Although WCF will be useful for some other scenarios we'll run in to. Thanks.

Comment: @sixto right, but i was refering to the client code that might have restrictions to run on .net 2.0 (framework, not clr) only, for instnace the might be running on an old server or something. Zipper, strictly speaking you dont have to host the wcf service in iis, you could 'self-host' it in a regular exe file or maybe as a windows service